# Positioning/Rendering issues in Safari (OSX and iPad) when adding CSS pulse animation

Tags: css, safari, position, css-animations, pulse

I wanted to create a pulsing animation on a vertically and horizontally centered image using CSS animations. This works fine in Firefox and Chrome (mobile and OSX versions). But is screwed up in Safari, the positioning of the image is incorrect.

The weird thing is that after switching desktops (three finger swipe left or right) and coming back to safari, the image is positioned correctly.

I created a jsfiddle to show the issue, I left out all prefixes except -webkit.

JSfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/stxnt1sb/9/

**HTML**

```
<article>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400/sports/">
</article>
```

**CSS**

```
article{
  position:relative;
  width:600px;
  height:400px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
img{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  width:100%;
  -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  -webkit-animation-name: pulse;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
}
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1) ;
  }
  33% {
    -webkit-transform:  translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1.05);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1) ;
  }
}
```

The image is positioned absolute within a relative container, centered with a translate(-50%,-50%). The pulsing is done with a css animation, animating the scale of the image.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to try a different approach than using a real `<img />` element. As your code suggests you want to scale the image based on its aspect ratio. However you will only be able to set the width or height to 100%, otherwise it will stretch the image out of proportions.

Sadly, in the case of Safari, I think the image is loaded after the stylesheet is rendered. This leaves Safari's render engine in doubt on what to do with the vertical positioning (as the height is not set at this point).

Therefore I suggest swapping the conventional `<img />` to something like this:

```css
article{
  position:relative;
  width:600px;
  height:400px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.pulsing-background{
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position:absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-animation-name: pulse;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
}
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    
    -webkit-transform: scale(1) ;
   
  }
  33% {
    
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
  
  }
  100% {
   
    -webkit-transform: scale(1) ;
   
  }
}
```

```html
<article>
  <figure style="background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/600/400/sports/)" class="pulsing-background"></figure>
</article>
```

This ensures that the child element (figure) is always the size of its parent. It is semantically not perfect, and you might also find a solution switching to [Flex-Box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) implementations. At least you now know where to look.

**EDIT:** Forgot to add margin: 0; in the snippet to reset the default `<figure />` styling in Safari.

Comment: You can still position elements while maintaining their aspect ratio ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cy96wfhd/))

Comment: @tim-s Absolutely! However, this would require you to know the dimensions of the image beforehand. I'm uncertain about the practical use case that the OP has in mind.

Using 'background-size: cover;' works with any aspect ratio and is a fool-proof way of implementing different aspect ratio images inside a container with a specific format. Although I don't like having to use the 'style' attribute for it.

Answer (score 1):

As Ricardo stated, Safari’s render engine is probably in doubt. Safari determines the transformed element needs a composite layer. These layers are special layers that are rendered separately. My guess is Safari doesn’t update the composite layer then the image is loaded.

That leaves a few options.

## 1: Set height and width attributes

I’m pretty certain this will fix it. Setting a width and height on the image allows Safari to predict the size before it’s loaded. Unfortunately it does require hard-coded values or an extra I/O read to determine the image’s size.

## 2: Force update

Paul Lewis, a.k.a. Aerotwist, created [CSS Triggers](http://csstriggers.com/), a list of CSS properties and what they trigger. You could set a property and trigger a redraw. In this particular case, I’m not sure if you need a layout, so the composite layer determines the size of it’s contents and resize accordingly, or a composite, where the layer simply changes position.

There are different ways to do this. You could set a CSS property, you could get information and trigger a refresh by doing so (e.g. `el.getComputedStyle()` and `el.offsetTop`), or you can simply do a `window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'))`. Use this as a last resort, as they may have implications on rendering performance.

## 3: Avoid composite layers

You’re using a transform to center align the image, and you have to set the transform in your animation, meaning you can’t reuse it for elements without that very same transform. Although the animation may only apply to that specific element, it’s a good practice to isolate responsibilities. The animation should work, whatever element you apply it to.

Anyway, there are other ways to center align elements.

The [display: table method](https://jsfiddle.net/xjox0f1f/) is old, but reliable. If you’re using modern browsers, [centering using Flexbox](https://davidwalsh.name/css-vertical-center-flexbox) is probably the easiest method.